# JavaFX draw pixels with PixelWriter results in gaps

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, drawing, pixel

I am drawing onto an ImageView in such way:

```
@FXML
void imgVDrag(MouseEvent event) {  //On Mouse Dragged
    pixelWriter.setColor((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY(), colPick.getValue());
}
```

If i move the mouse too fast it results in gaps between the pixels. Do i have to use another event or is there any other solution?

Comment: You could set a game loop, and a x and y variable array for mouse, then update every time it changes, add to end and pop of beginning. Idk.

Comment: draw lines between positions instead of pixels.